# Changing default project save type CS5.5

Tags: flash, adobe, save, flash-cs5

I got Adobe Creative Suite 5.5, and all the projects in company are made in 5.0. And **i can't simply save by ctrl+s** because **Flash** (thats concrete program i am asking about) want to save in 5.5. So every time i have to push **file-> save as-> change from 5.5 to 5.0.** I was trying to find somewhere, where to change it, but i didnt manage to.

Anyone knows the solution to my problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

never worked in any of the prior versions of flash - i'd be surprised if adobe actually changed this.

i always just saved with ctrl+s/cmd+s all day long and try to remember to save the last version with "save as ..." - pain in the a** but only way out :(

Comment: this is not happening... nooo :(